# Share blockchain data between bitcoin-core and btc-1

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, segwit2x

I am currently running a BTC-1 node and would like to setup an additional core node before the November fork. Ideally, I would avoid the need to resync the entire blockchain again. Is it possible for me to locally copy the blockchain data I have already downloaded for btc-1 and use it to avoid a full resync with bitcoin-core?

Comment: Not sure about BTC-1, but [my question about BCH/Bitcoin ABC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68493/bitcoin-abc-when-fed-bitcoin-core-chain-syncs-to-aug-1-623am-2017-then-freeze) could be relevant.  You might want to check that.